How to remove the notification count from app icons in the Ubuntu 24.04 dock
I seem to not be the only one, who finds the behaviour of the new notification count on app icons in the dock confusing (similar questions). Slack has its own mechanism of counting unread messages. Even when I clear all of them, the notification count in the dock still shows some number:

This is connected to the number of uncleared notifications in the notification list. Only after clearing all of the notifications there, the notification count goes away.
I could not find a way to disable the notification count on app icons in the dock. There is neither a relevant setting in Ubuntu Desktop > Dock nor in Notifications > Slack.
How to remove the notification count from app icons in the dock, while keeping notification pop-ups?
